# Python: how do I save a row in reader and preserve its context?

Tags: python, csv

Using Python, I wrote the following script to index through a row in csv.reader and compare it to relevant values from the previous row:

```
source = open('sourcefile')
reader = csv.reader(source)
with open('targetfile','w') as f:
    for row in reader:
        if row[1] == "NA" and row[2] == "NA":
            prevrow = row
            line = row
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerow(line)
     else:
         while row[1] == prevrow[1]:
             if row[1] == prevrow[3]:
                cumbid = cumbid + row[2]
                line = row[0]  + "," + row[1]  + "," + cumbid  + "," + prevrow[3]  + "," + prevrow[4] + "," +  str(int(float(prevrow[5]))-int(float(cumbid)))  + "," + prevrow[6]  + "," + prevrow[7] + "," + prevrow[8] + "," + prevrow[9] + "," + prevrow[10] + "," + prevrow[11] + "," + prevrow[12] + "," + prevrow[13] + "," + prevrow[14] + "," + ","
                prevrow = line
            elif row[1] == prevrow[4]:
                cumask = cumask + row[2]
                line = row[0]  + "," + row[1]  + "," + cumask  + "," + prevrow[3]  + "," + prevrow[4] + "," +  prevrow[5]  + "," + str(int(float(prevrow[6]))-int(float(cumask)))  + "," + prevrow[7] + "," + prevrow[8] + "," + prevrow[9] + "," + prevrow[10] + "," + prevrow[11] + "," + prevrow[12] + "," + prevrow[13] + "," + prevrow[14] + "," + "," 
                prevrow = line
        else:
            if row[1] == prevrow[3] and row[2] < prevrow[5]:                       
                cumbid = row[2]
                line = row[0]  + "," + row[1]  + "," + row[2]  + "," + prevrow[3]  + "," + prevrow[4] + "," +  str(int(float(prevrow[5]))-int(float(row[2])))  + "," + prevrow[6]  + "," + prevrow[7] + "," + prevrow[8] + "," + prevrow[9] + "," + prevrow[10] + "," + prevrow[11] + "," + prevrow[12] + "," + prevrow[13] + "," + prevrow[14] + "," + "," 

                prevrow = line
                print prevrow
                print prevrow[0]+ " " + prevrow[1]+ " " + prevrow[2]+ " " + prevrow[3]+ " " + prevrow[4]+ " " + prevrow[5]+ " " + prevrow[6]
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(line.split())   
            elif row[1] == prevrow[4] and row[2] < prevrow[6]:                  
                cumask = row[2]
                line = row[0]  + "," + row[1]  + "," + row[2]  + "," + prevrow[3]  + "," + prevrow[4] + "," +  prevrow[5]  + "," + str(int(float(prevrow[6]))-int(float(row[2])))  + "," + prevrow[7] + "," + prevrow[8] + "," + prevrow[9] + "," + prevrow[10] + "," + prevrow[11] + "," + prevrow[12] + "," + prevrow[13] + "," + prevrow[14] + "," + "," 
                prevrow = line
                print prevrow
                print prevrow[0]+ " " + prevrow[1]+ " " + prevrow[2]+ " " + prevrow[3]+ " " + prevrow[4]+ " " + prevrow[5]+ " " + prevrow[6]
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(line.split())   
            elif row[1] == prevrow[3] and row[2] == prevrow[5] :                 
                line = row[0]  + "," + row[1]  + "," + row[2]  + "," + prevrow[7]  + "," + prevrow[4] + "," +  prevrow[8] + "," + prevrow[6]  + "," + prevrow[11] + "," + prevrow[12] + "," + prevrow[9] + "," + prevrow[10] + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," 
                prevrow = line
                print prevrow
                print prevrow[0]+ " " + prevrow[1]+ " " + prevrow[2]+ " " + prevrow[3]+ " " + prevrow[4]+ " " + prevrow[5]+ " " + prevrow[6]
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(line.split())   
            elif row[1] == prevrow[4] and row[2] == prevrow[6]:                   #the trade was on the offer and took it all out--we have to refer to the 2nd level of the book
                line = row[0]  + "," + row[1]  + "," + row[2]  + "," + prevrow[3]  + "," + prevrow[9] + "," +  prevrow[5]  + "," + prevrow[10]  + "," + prevrow[7] + "," + prevrow[8] + "," + prevrow[13] + "," + prevrow[14] + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," + "," 
                prevrow = line
                print prevrow
                print prevrow[0]+ " " + prevrow[1]+ " " + prevrow[2]+ " " + prevrow[3]+ " " + prevrow[4]+ " " + prevrow[5]+ " " + prevrow[6]
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(line.split())   
            elif row[1] == prevrow[1] and row[1] == prevrow[3] :                  #trade was on the bid, and the prev row was also a trade--decrement bid size
                line = row[0]  + "," + row[1]  + "," + row[2]  + "," + prevrow[3]  + "," + prevrow[4] + "," +  str(int(float(prevrow[5]))-int(float(row[2])))  + "," + prevrow[6]  + "," + prevrow[7] + "," + prevrow[8] + "," + prevrow[9] + "," + prevrow[10] + "," + prevrow[11] + "," + prevrow[12] + "," + prevrow[13] + "," + prevrow[14] + "," + "," 
                prevrow = line
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(line.split())   
            elif row[1] == prevrow[1] and row[1] == prevrow[4] :                    #trade was on the offer, and the prev row was also a trade--decrement ask size
                line = row[0]  + "," + row[1]  + "," + row[2]  + "," + prevrow[3]  + "," + prevrow[4] + "," +  prevrow[5]  + "," + str(int(float(prevrow[6]))-int(float(row[2])))  + "," + prevrow[7] + "," + prevrow[8] + "," + prevrow[9] + "," + prevrow[10] + "," + prevrow[11] + "," + prevrow[12] + "," + prevrow[13] + "," + prevrow[14] + "," + "," 
                prevrow = line
                writer = csv.writer(f)
                writer.writerow(line.split())
```

However, these subsequent lines generate the following:

## code

```
print prevrow
print prevrow[0]+ " " + prevrow[1]+ " " + prevrow[2]+ " " + prevrow[3]+ " " + prevrow[4]+ " " + prevrow[5]+ " " + prevrow[6]
```

## output

```
20100628000120702,12392.0,1.0,12392.0,12393.0,5.0
2 0 1 0 0 6 2
```

I would have liked both lines of output to be identical, so that a comparison like row[1] == prevrow[1] would compare 12392.0 to the 2nd item in the previous row (12392.0) instead of the 2nd character in the row (0).  So, my problem is that prevrow has become a list of chars, and when I attempt to index the items in prevrow the way I can index items in row, I instead seem to get an index of the chars in the list.

How do I save a current "row" and preserve its context?

Comment: I think you haven't included your full code; what happens in the while loop there?

Comment: Well, it does a variety of things with more control loops. I am just trying to index through a saved previous row object the same way I can the current row object.

Comment: *nothing* in your example explains prevrow being a string, so the error is in the code we cannot see.

Comment: Sorry, I have now included the rest of the code.

Comment: There, now your error is quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Use tee to create two virtual iterators, increment one, and then zip them, to get a sequence of (lastrow,currentrow) tuples. (See the `pairwise` recipe in the [itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes).)

Then you can write:

```
for prevrow,row in pairwise(reader):
    ... etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing strings in `line` and storing them in `prevrow`; store a list instead:

```
line = row[:2] + [cumbid] + prevrow[3:5] + [str(int(float(prevrow[5])) - int(float(cumbid)))] + prevrow[6:15]
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Of course. That is something I did elsewhere, and unfortunately forgot. Thanks!